# Photoshop Automation

Tags: adobe-photoshop, automation

I'm am fairly new to the photoshop automation tools, but I am a long time user of photoshop.

I am trying to find a way to export each of 8 layers inside of a group individually while maintaining the visibility of the other layers in the project. What I am trying to accomplish is a exporting 8 PNG images that just have a single element replaced.

My current method is to manually unhide each one of the 8 layers and manually export.

I am looking for some behavior that is similar "extract assets" where the exported files use the layer name.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure I understand your question, but have you thought about using [layer comps](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/layer-comps.html)? It's fairly simple, it's like a snapshot of multiple layers you want turned on at the same time.

Once you have this set up, you can then chose FILE> SCRIPTS> LAYER COMPS TO FILES and that will export each layer comp separately.